# Update 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3.-p1 results in 500 error

Tags: magento2.4.2-p1, version-upgrade

No errors during update after lowering composer back down from 2.2.3 to 2.1.4 but site/backend results in 500 error.

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()

#1
/home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()

#2 /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get()

#3 /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()

#4 /home/user/web/domain.com/pu" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.12.12, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm-domain.com.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "https://domain.com"

2022/01/02 17:01:53 [error] 24350#24350: *2297 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Class 'Laminas\Mvc\Controller\PluginManagerSM2' not found in /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/autoload.php on line 16PHP message: PHP Warning:  Class 'Laminas\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill' not found in /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/laminas/laminas-form/autoload/formElementManagerPolyfill.php on line 17PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\RemoteStorage\Driver\Cache\CacheFactory' not found in /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed and upgraded from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3-p1 by upgrading Composer to current version 2.2.4.

The error above was then fixed by restarting php 7.4 on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case fresh Magento 2.4.1 (Nginx on ubuntu) solution (by David Lambauer) worked:

In terminal:

> cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
>
> ls

Open your Nginx config file:

code magento24.local.config
Find "fastcgi_buffers"

I change it like that:

```
    #fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
```

Save that config file. Restart Nginx :

sudo service Nginx restart

Comment: Thanks for the post. Unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue.